# Request.IsHttps and Request.Scheme are showing that request is HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working with an .Net Core web app and I need to verify the request is HTTPS. I have installed a certificate in Azure with Let's encrypt and I have a cloudflare CDN but always shows me as if the request was not HTTPS.

I've used

```
this.Request.Scheme.Equals("https")
```

and

```
this.Request.IsHttps
```

Do you have any idea what's happenning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cloudflare CDN, although it serves your requests as HTTPS, is actually making the request to your website as HTTP.

You are likely using Cloudflare's [Flexible mode](https://troyhunt.com/cloudflare-ssl-and-unhealthy-security-absolutism). You likely want to use one of the [Full](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-) modes.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your CDN (Cloudflare) is sending requests to your web server over HTTP.

You can either instruct Cloudflare to only use HTTPS, or enforce this locally via ASP.NET.

If Kestrel is exposed to the internet directly, then you can actually instruct Kestrel to redirect requests from HTTP to HTTPS.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();            // <=== Add this =====
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();    // <=== Add this =====
}
```